# Is there a way to use .reduce() on an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add all the items I have in my JavaScript array together * the item quantity. I have an array of objects like so:

```
var products = [ {price: 1, quantity: 2},
                  {price: 4, quantity: 1},
                  {price: 2, quantity: 1} ]
```

Right now I'm using

```
var sum = 0;
products.forEach(function(item){
  sum += item.price * item.quantity;
})
return sum;
```

Which works, but I'm just wondering if I can refactor this using .reduce(). So far I haven't had any luck as I've tried mapping it out and reducing it as well. Is it possible to do this with reduce?

Comment: Show us your attempt to use `reduce` and we'll help you get it working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, it's the most standard use case of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var sum = products.reduce((sum, p) => sum + p.price*p.quantity, 0);
```